# regex to match character in specific position

Tags: regex

I need to come up with a regex to look for only letters A, F or E on the position 9 of a given text. I am really new with regex, did some searching and couldn't find any similar response. what i have so far is:

```
/^.{9}A/
```

This command seems to work to find letter A on the space nine, but how can I add the other 2 letters to the regex?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You say you're looking for C, F or E but looking for A in your example, so please include in the brackets any other letters you want to match, but what you're looking for is:

```
/^.{8}[CFE]/
```

It should be `{8}` rather than `{9}` because the way you had it, it'll match the first 9 characters and then match your letter in position 10.

Comment: I am trying to do a regex match so that a password is max 8 characters long and the 4th character has to be a digit ^{3}[0-9].[a-z0-9]{8}$  this is what I have so far but I believe it is wrong

Comment: @user6248190 you can do it like this: `^.{3}[0-9]{5}$`

Answer (score 4):

Use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
/^.{9}[CFE]/
```

- `[CFE]` matches *one* of `C`, `F` or `E`

Or use the [`|`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) meta-character (alternation):

```
/^.{9}(?:C|F|E)/
```

Comment: @tchelidze Adding `$` will solve the problem (if OP wants). I'm not sure what language/tool they're using.

Answer (score 1):

This way can also solve the problem

```
/^.{8}A|^.{8}F|^.{8}E/;
```

you have to use 8 instead of 9 if you want to match the character on the 9th position