# Regex to match character in specific position and specific length

Tags: python, regex

I need to find string with length of 12 and contains in the 7 position the char "U".

I have the following strings:

```
SUPERHUMANLY
DFGDFGDFGGFG
SUPSRHTMANLY
DFGDFGUFGGFG
```

Only the following **should** matched:

```
SUPERHUMANLY
DFGDFGUFGGFG
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789929/regex-to-match-character-in-specific-position) link I know how to get match on the 7 position:

```
^.{6}[U]
```

But I want to get match on only letters with specific length, so I tried `^.{6}[U]{12}`, `^(.{6}[U]){12}` and `^.{6}[U].{12}` without success.

How can I combine the length of the string with the position ?

Comment: If you are not limited to regex, you may use `[s for s in my_strings if len(s) == 12 and s[6] == "U"]` ([demo](https://ideone.com/gaVc3j))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simple :

```
^.{6}U.{5}$
```

Comment: Some explanation to answer would be great. :)

Comment: @CappY: Such basic regex doesn't really need explanation. `.` stands for any character but newline and `{5}` stands for 5 occurrences of previous character.