How should I format this regex to find this desired amino acid sequence?
I am looking for an amino acid within sequences in a fasta file. I am checking to see if the 564th amino acid in the sequence is a V, I, or E. The file that is being accessed was read in and processed as a part of another function. The code is below:
with open("/Users/adia/Downloads/FGFR_fusion.fasta",'r') as fasta:
    test = fasta.read()
    test = test.split(">")
    del test[0]
    out = open("/Users/adia/Desktop/PSB HW_6.txt", 'w')
    for x in test:
        if 'fibroblast growth factor receptor 1 isoform' in x:
            out.write(x)  

with open("/Users/adia/Desktop/PSB HW_6.txt", 'r') as filtered:
    test2 = filtered.read()
    out = open("/Users/adia/Desktop/564ID.txt", 'w')
    
   ** AA564 = re.compile('^M.{562}[IVE]')**
    matches = re.finditer(AA564,test2)

    found = [] 
    for match in matches: 
        found.append(match.group(0))
        print(f"Found {match.group(0)} at position {match.start()}.\n")
            
    if found == []:
            print("No match found.")

No match found.

I know for a fact there is at least one match (I read and separated each sequence myself) but for whatever reason, this does not work.
I have tried a ton of variations of this regex:

re.compile('M.{562}[IVE]')
re.compile('^M.{562}[IVE]')
re.compile('^M.{562}[IVE]',re.M)
re.compile('^M.{562}[IVE]',re.DOTALL)
re.compile('M.{562}[IVE].*')
re.compile('^M.{562}[IVE].*')
re.compile('^M[GALMFWKQESOVICYHRNDT]{562}[IVE]')
re.compile('M[GALMFWKQESOVICYHRNDT]{562}[IVE]')
re.compile('^M[A-Z]{562}[IVE]'

It may have something to do with how the file is formatted when its written out the first time, as it is the input in the part I am having trouble with. But I checked, and when its read out and back in, both times it is a string. I can't edit it further or else I can't use regex. I have tried using regex101 to see where the discrepancy is, but nothing is obvious. Can anyone provide insight on how to resolve this?
TIA!

You missed the re.M, re.compile('^M.{562}[IVE]', re.M)

@WiktorStribiżew I just tried with re.M and it didn't work. I actually tried re.M and re.DOTALL, I forgot to include that.

Mind that re.DOTALL / re.S simply make . match \n, LF, line feed, characters. re.M makes ^ match the position at the start of the text and also the positions right after \n.

Also, if you are working with UTF8 BOM files, you should use open("/Users/adia/Downloads/FGFR_fusion.fasta",'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'). Or at least account for the 3 bytes at the start of your data.

Is that so you all have data to try to resolve the question?

Another point to consider: you might have multibyte characters, i.e. base letters + diacritics, and . does not match them as a single graphemes, so there will be a count mismatch between what you see and what the pattern with .{x} matches.

Can you share the file that you are working with?

Consider using bioinformatics packages designed for this type of tasks. For example, you can create a one-record bed file to extract amino acid just at this position and use bedtools, which can be installed, for example, using conda. Bioinformatics tools that deal with fasta files take into account multi-line fasta sequences too.

@Thefourthbird I don't see an option to do so. are you able to tell me how?

@TimurShtatland because this is for a class, I am not able to use something like that. I think the only package I could use is biopython, and even I haven't worked with it yet.

Biopython (which can be also installed with conda) is another good choice. See, for example, Using Biopython (Python) to extract sequence from FASTA file - Stack Overflow

@TimurShtatland Can I use biopython even though the file I am reading in is a .txt file? Most of the documentation is for traditional sequence files like fasta or clustal.

@axr Use Biopython with the original file, to filter it based on the sequence id and also to find the amino acids at specific positions.

@TimurShtatland I am required to create two separate functions, which is unfortunate.

Did you try:
AA564 = re.compile(r'^M.{562}[IVE]')

@ChefAharoni yes. its second in the list of variations I tried.

@axr I didn't see the r at the beginning of the statement

@ChefAharoni AH I see. I tried it just now and it still can't find any matches.

There is  no difference between the version with r and without since the texts are the same (^M.{562}[IVE]). The problem is in the data, and we have no access to the real files.

@WiktorStribiżew is there a way to attach files to the question? I made an attempt but didn't see a way. I am bit new to Stack.

Please don't add a whole file to the question. Just add a few lines that show the wanted data.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52515582/regex-to-match-character-in-specific-position-and-specific-length

input FGFR_fusion.fasta:
>fibroblast growth factor receptor 1 isoform
AAAAAAAAAE

with code (see regex to match character in specific position ):
import re 

with open("FGFR_fusion.fasta",'r') as fasta:
    test = fasta.read()
    
    print('test : ', test)
    test2 = test.split(">")[1].split('\n')[1]
    
    print('test2 : ', test2)
    # del test[1]
    
    print('test2 : ', test2)
    
    
    out = open("PSB HW_6.txt", 'w')
    for x in test.split(">"):
        
        print('x : ', x)
        
        if 'fibroblast growth factor receptor 1 isoform' in x:
            
            print('test2 : ', test2)
            out.write(test2)  
            out.close()

with open("PSB HW_6.txt", 'r') as filtered:
    test2 = filtered.read()
    
    print('test2 : ', test2)
    
    out = open("10ID.txt", 'w')
    
    AA10 = re.compile('^.{9}[IVE]')
    matches = re.finditer(AA10,test2)
    
    print('matches : ', matches)

    found = [] 
    for match in matches: 
        print('match.group() : ', match.group())
        found.append(match.group())
        print(f"Found {match.group(0)} at position {match.start()}\n")
        out.write(match.group()[9])  
        out.close()
            
    if found == []:
            print("No match found.")

output :
test :  >fibroblast growth factor receptor 1 isoform
AAAAAAAAAE

    test2 :  AAAAAAAAAE
    test2 :  AAAAAAAAAE
    x :  
    x :  fibroblast growth factor receptor 1 isoform
    AAAAAAAAAE
    
    test2 :  AAAAAAAAAE
    test2 :  AAAAAAAAAE
    matches :  <callable_iterator object at 0x7fd97064cb50>
    match.group() :  AAAAAAAAAE
    Found AAAAAAAAAE at position 0

and files :
PSB HW_6.txt : AAAAAAAAAE ;
10ID.txt    :  E
With Biopython, same input and outputs, code:
 import Bio

print('\n-------------------------------')

print('\n Biopython Version : ', Bio.__version__)

print('\n-------------------------------')

from Bio import SeqIO


with open("FGFR_fusion.fasta",'r') as fasta:
    test = SeqIO.parse(fasta, 'fasta') 
    
    print('test : ', test)
    
    for record in test:
        print('record : ', record)
        print('record.id : ', record.id , 'record.seq : ', record.seq)
        
        # for i in dir(record):
        #     print(i)

    
        out = open("PSB HW_6.txt", 'w')
        
        if 'fibroblast growth factor receptor 1 isoform' in record.description:
            
            print("record.description : ", record.description)
            print('OK')
            
            out.write(str(record.seq))  
            out.close()
            
    
        out = open("10ID.txt",  'w')
        
        found = [] 
    
        if record.seq[9] in ['I','V','E']:

            
            found.append(record.seq[9])
            print(f"Found {record.seq[9]} at position 10\n")
            out.write(record.seq[9])  
        out.close()
            
    if found == []:
            print("No match found.")

