# Pattern match at a specific column number with a particular string . No delimiter or separator

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I want to search a file to output rows matching a particular value at specific column number. There is no delimiter involved. For example:

```
IloveA
IloveB
IloveC
IloveA
IloveD
IloveA
Ilove A
```

Output :

```
IloveA
IloveA
IloveA
```

Here the important point to note it should print only if A is present at 6th column.

Comment: `grep '^.....A'` ....

Comment: If you're interested in a regex-based solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789929/regex-to-match-character-in-specific-position

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep '^.....A'` or more generally `grep -E '^.{5}A'`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem, you need to print the rows matching a pattern within the range of the first 5 characters, but only if the 6<sup>th</sup> character is `A`. This can be done in two steps:

- filter out the rows with the 6<sup>th</sup> character equal to `A` and capture the first 5 characters at the same time;
- print the line, if the captured sequence matches your pattern.

The following is a sample implementation of the above in Perl:

```sh
perl -l -n -e 'print if /^(.{5})A/ and $1 =~ /ove/' input-file.txt
```

The Perl code prints the next line read from the file (implicit argument `$_`) if the line matches `/^(.{5})A/`. As a result of [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), `$1` (the first and the only capturing group) contains the first five characters. Then, if `$1` matches `/ove/` (a sample pattern that you'd change), the second `if` condition is true, and the line is printed to standard output.